# Examples non experiments in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, examples-counterexamples

I'm reading a book on probability theory and they say that an experiment is

> Any procedure that has not got a pre-determined outcome

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiment_(probability_theory)) page they, instead, that an experiment should:

- be infinitely repeatable
- have well-defined set of possible outcomes

Now, I really don't see why it has to be infinitely repeatable. I mean, it makes sense only for frequentist probability right? Surely not for bayesian one.

Anyway, my question is: then what is NOT an experiment? what are some examples of procedures that are not experiments?

**My Solution**

My idea is that the following are experiments:

- Tossing a fair coin, and looking at which side is facing upward after landing.
- Tossing a fair dice, and looking at which side is facing upward after landing.
- Picking up a numbered ball from within a box (where balls are placed randomly and the picking up mechanism is fair) and looking at the number of the ball.

However, I can't quite make up any sensible example of something that is NOT an experiment. For instance, I think that also the following is an experiment:

- Tossing a non-fair coin that always lands on HEAD and looking at the side facing upwards.

because even though the coin is biased, it is infinitely repeatable and has well-defined set of possible outcomes.

What are some examples of non-experiments?

Comment: I wouldn't only read these things in the context of probability theory. Say you melt a lump of copper and measure the temperature that it takes to do that. You draw a conclusion about the melting point of copper, and you expect your conclusion to hold in other instances of melting copper. There you have "infinite repeatability."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of a procedure that is not infintely repeatable is drawing a marble from an urn with a finite number of red and blue marbles in it, without replacement, and observing the color.

It has a well-defined set of possible outcomes (i.e. $\{\text{Blue},\text{Red}\}$), but it is not infinitely repeatable. Eventually we will run out of marbles.

Comment: So this would not be considered an experiment in the statistical sense? But surely we could build a probability space on this..

Comment: We never said it is impossible to build a probability space on this, just that it is not a valid experiment according to the necessary conditions you imposed on it.

Comment: You can fill the urn back and restart from the beginning. I am not sure that is what is meant by 'infinitely repeatable".

Comment: @molarmass okay apologies, maybe I wasn't very clear in the question. My understanding is that probability is built on top of an experiment. We start with an experiment, then we consider its outcomes, we create the sample space. Then we define the event space as some sigma algebra on it. Then we define a probability measure. Then a probability space, and so on.... So my understanding was that if something is not an experiment, then we can't build anything on it.

Comment: In an experiment, the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ should stay constant. However, when we are repeatedly taking marbles out of the urn, the probabilities of picking a red or blue one change constantly, so it is not a valid experiment. If you _did_ replace the marble, then it _would_ be a valid experiment.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Although the "non-repeatability" part was kind of okay. But what about the "well-defined set of outcomes"? Is there any such example?

Comment: That basically assures that the outcome space $\Omega$ is unambiguously defined, i.e. we all agree what could _possibly_ happen. That is necessary to construct $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: Yes exactly! But can you think of any such example? I can't really think of any

Comment: For instance, the outcome space $\Omega=\{x:x \text{ is one of the 5 best songs of 2018}\}$ is not well-defined because (1) we do not necessarily agree on what the best songs are, and (2) 2018 is not over yet, so there may be better songs in the future. This is not a suitable outcome space.

Comment: I see what you mean! That's quite a simple example, but I was just so stuck into the theory that I couldn't think of anything different from coins and dice!

Comment: Hold on though. In the example in your answer you say that it not an experiment. So this mean that all the problems where we draw something without replacements are not experiements and so it doesn't make sense to define probabilities?

Comment: What _can_ be an experiment is the following: draw $k$ marbles out of an urn with $n$ marbles without replacement, with $k<n$. Then put all marbles back and repeat. The difference that in this case, drawing $k$ marbles is just 1 trial, and each trial starts with the same initial conditions. So the probabilities stay constant. In my previous example, every marble we drew from the urn was a separate trial, which is a subtle but crucial difference.

Comment: That is such a small difference that it shouldn't make a difference, but it does indeed! Thanks a lot!